# How to display no of records ( Count ) in-front of each categories in ASP.NET webpage?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am developing a website with ASP.NET and My DB is MYSQL. I want to display how much records that have for each categories in parenthesis. 
Like below image

[image]

Sure After load the page I can asynchronously call for a function which count the records for each category. But if I have millions of records and If I have 50 categories I have to go thorough 50 times in millions of records to get the count for each record. My gut says it will lead to serious performance issue.

So how developers address this problem? Some one told me that Implement a Count table and for each record I am adding to DB increment this count and If user delete a record decrements this counter. That make sense. But what happen if two users try to add a record and other user try to void a record. Then what will happen? Is that operation will cause to error?

what is your opinion regarding this? What is best performance wise? 
Counting the each record asynchronously?
Maintains a count table? 
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database has two tables called categories, and records I would get the categories using a query such as;

```
SELECT categories.name, COUNT(*) as records_count
FROM categories LEFT JOIN records ON categories.id = recoords.categories_id
GROUP BY categories.id
```

For performance I would cache this result.

Comment: What you mean by Cache? Doesn't this solution lead to performance issue? Actually this is the idea what I have up to now. I mean for each time user load the page this query will run for 50 categories ( 50 times ) with million records. ?

Comment: If properly configured MySQL will [cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) the results anyway. If indexed correctly even the initial query pre-cache may not take as long as you think. Only testing will really tell. By cache, I meant storing the result in application memory, or a dedicated cache system like memcached.